# Why show me one empty col-md-3 on start

Tags: php, html

For example, if I have 4 images in a database, show me one empty `<div class="col-md-3"><img src="../uploads/" class="float-start mb-2" alt=""></div>` and 4 images. Don't know why show me this empty.

```
<main>
    <!-- Main START -->
    <section class="pt-0">
        <div class="container position-relative" data-sticky-container>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Main Content START -->
                <div class="col-lg-12 mb-7">
                    <!-- Images -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <img src="../uploads/<?php echo $image['file_name']; ?>" class="float-start mb-2" alt="<?php echo $image['file_name']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <!-- Main Content END -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Main END -->

</main>
```

Comment: There must be a problem with the way you've created the `$images` array. Show that code.

Comment: What does `var_dump($images);` show?

Comment: I can't edit the code. Here is ``$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT `file_name`, `photo_signature` FROM `images` WHERE `new_id` = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->bind_result($file_name, $photo_signature);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        // Add result to accounts array
        $images[] = ['file_name' => $file_name, 'photo_signature' => $photo_signature];
    }``

Comment: Why can't you edit the code? Just click on the "Edit" link below the question.

Comment: var_dump($images); result `array(5) { ["file_name"]=> string(0) "" [0]=> array(2) { ["file_name"]=> string(24) "FB_IMG_1658333691406.jpg" ["photo_signature"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(2) { ["file_name"]=> string(24) "FB_IMG_1658333685213.jpg" ["photo_signature"]=> string(0) "" } [2]=> array(2) { ["file_name"]=> string(24) "FB_IMG_1658333680226.jpg" ["photo_signature"]=> string(0) "" } [3]=> array(2) { ["file_name"]=> string(24) "FB_IMG_1658333676582.jpg" ["photo_signature"]=> string(0) "" } }`

Comment: You need `$images = [];` before the loop to initialize it.

Comment: Where did `$images['file_name']` come from? I suspect you used the same variable `$images` earlier in the code. Avoid reusing variable names.

Comment: @Barmar yes when add `$images = [];` before `while ($stmt->fetch()) {` this is working. Thank you man